# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Damage nbt can't be used to select item entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to select a diamond axe which is on the ground and has no durability used up. I have the command `execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_axe",Count:1b,Damage:0}}] at @s run say hi`, but when I throw an axe on the ground, in creative or survival, having gotten the axe through the inventory or with`/give`, it does nothing. I've added b, s, l, f, and d after the 0 in the Damage selector, and still nothing. I can give myself a diamond axe with some amount of damage, but I can't seem to select it off the ground. Why is this/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Damage` belongs in the `tag` tag. `/data get entity @e[type=item,sort=nearest,limit=1]` is your friend in these cases, or F3+I. Also, maybe the Damage tag doesn't exist on fresh items.

Comment: Just checked the wiki, and Damage is indeed inside the `tag` tag.  It does default to 0, though, so it should be there on any item that has the tag (I had thought that 0 meant the item was destroyed, but that doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: Sorry but on a side note how can I put the damage of a tool into a scoreboard, if it's in a player's inventory? Or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @Nik3141 In theory it's a separate question, but in practice you can just look at the wiki. The page is called "chunk format" and has EVERYTHING about NBT.

Comment: @FabianRöling Sorry I looked at it but I can't find anything about tool durability in the inventory. I see dropped items, mobs, dynamic tiles, blocks, chunks, projectiles, vehicles and other. Could you link the portion of the wiki with it or should I ask a new question for it?

Comment: That page is full of expandable sections, so simple browser search won't help you. Just go by what seems useful, in this case the item entity. You know that item entities have NBT of items, so expand that and you see "tags common to all items", which you can expand, there you see "additional information about the item" with a link. Click that and you see "Damage" in the "general tags" section. Going through it like this also shows you the entire path from the world via the entity to the smallest bit of NBT information. You can use this path in NBT as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Damage` is in the `tag` tag and you need the "byte" type:

```
{Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_axe",Count:1b,tag:{Damage:0b}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/data get entity @s Inventory` shows that undamaged items do not have a `Damage` tag. You have to supply it with `/give @s diamond_axe{Damage:0}`.